# assembler function not executing when esp is not exetremely low

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, nasm, real-mode

Im currently writing an assembler program that runs in real mode.
I compile it using NASM.
My problem is that if I try to call one function from an other it only executes if I subtract a verry high value from esp (70) or if I dont have any arguments pushed.
I think there is something wrong with the way I call functions but I cant figure out what.

The comlete code:

```
; boot.asm
[ORG 0x7c00] ;set base addresse

  ;mov ax, 0x7c0
  xor ax, ax ; set zero
  mov ds, ax ; set data pointer

  mov ss, ax ; set stack start ptr
  mov sp, 0x2000
  add sp, ax

  call main

hang:
  jmp hang

main:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp

  push 0x13
  call setVideoMode_mode
  add esp, 2

  push 2
  push 320*200
  call clearScreen_char_n
  add esp, 4

  push 100
  call drawVerticalLine
  add esp, 2

  nop
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret


setVideoMode_mode:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp

  mov ah, 0x00 ;change mode command
  mov al, [ebp+6] ;video mode
  int 0x10 ;execute command


  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret

putPixel_pos_char:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  sub esp, 16 ; 3 local vars

  mov eax, DWORD [ebp+8] ;POS
  mov WORD [ebp-12], ax
  mov eax, DWORD [ebp+6] ;CHAR
  mov WORD [ebp-8], ax


  mov DWORD [ebp-4], 0xA0000 ;STD VIDEO POINTER

  mov eax, [ebp-12]
  add eax, DWORD [ebp-4]

  movzx edx, WORD [ebp-8]
  mov BYTE [eax], dl

  nop


;   leave
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret

;----------------------------
```

The problematic function:

```
drawVerticalLine: ;doing debugging stuf at the moment
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  sub esp, 16 ;the function call only works with 70 or higher / no arguments for this function

  mov eax, DWORD [ebp+6]
  mov WORD [ebp-4], ax

  push 4
  push 320*200
  call clearScreen_char_n ;not working (should make the screen red)
  add esp, 4

  nop
  mov esp, ebp
  push ebp
  ret


clearScreen_char_n:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp
  sub esp, 32

  mov eax, DWORD [ebp+8]
  mov WORD [ebp-12], ax ; CHAR
  mov eax, DWORD [ebp+6]
  mov WORD [ebp-8], ax ; N


  mov DWORD [ebp-4], 0 ; COUNTER


  jmp .LoopCompare

.LoopBody:

  push WORD [ebp-4] ;COUNTER
  push WORD [ebp-12] ;CHAR

  call putPixel_pos_char
  add esp, 4

  inc DWORD[ebp-4] ;COUNTER ++ 
.LoopCompare:
  mov ax, WORD [ebp-8] ;N
  cmp ax, WORD [ebp-4] ;COUNTER

  jne .LoopBody ;NOT EQUAL

  nop
  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret



times 510-($-$$) db 0

  db 0x55 ;mark bootsector
  db 0xAA
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I just noticed an even more strange thing:
If I debug with gdb and logg sp after each instruction (breakpoints + x/x $sp)(except the loop) it magicaly works how it should.
If I run with gdb without any breakpoints it again doesnt work.

Comment: In real mode only `sp` matters for a `call`/`ret` pair. You can however store and load to `esp` granted its value is not above the segment limit (which is 64KiB in real mode). Long story short: you should not use `esp`.

Comment: What "extremely high value"?  Is it larger than 2^16, so ESP wraps to outside the segment limit, and thus your `[ebp-4]` accesses will be to `0xffff1234`, outside the SS segment limit like Margaret said?  downvoted for lack of details so this isn't a [mcve].  Use a debugger to show the actual ESP value when it fails, and what you subtracted.  (Then it would be worth an upvote.)

Comment: 70 isn't "very high".  But anyway, how does it fail, exactly?  And what numeric value is in the full ESP when it works / fails?

Comment: I'd be curious if you would post your complete code.

Comment: I just posted the whold file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> mov DWORD [ebp-4], 0xA0000 ;STD VIDEO POINTER
> mov eax, [ebp-12]
> add eax, DWORD [ebp-4]
> movzx edx, WORD [ebp-8]
> mov BYTE [eax], dl
> ```

The troubles in your program come from the fact that the above instruction `mov BYTE [eax], dl` overwrites memory erroneously!

Because your entire program runs in the **real address mode**, you can't (*) access the video memory through its linear address at 0xA0000. You need to setup a segment register with 0xA000 and use a 16-bit offset within that segment.

```
putPixel_pos_char:
    push bp
    mov  bp, sp
    push ds
    mov  ax, 0xA000     ; Segment of graphical video memory
    mov  ds, ax
    mov  al, [bp+4]     ; 1st arg : Color
    mov  bp, [bp+6]     ; 2nd arg : Position in video memory 0-63999
    mov  [ds:bp], al
    pop  ds
    pop  bp
    ret
```

Tip: Don't setup local variables if the code doesn't really require it!

Also because this program runs in the **real address mode**, you should stop using `ESP` and `EBP` the way you do. Only use the 16-bit portions `sp` and `bp`.

(*) You *can*, but setting up the **unreal address mode** might not be worth the trouble for the short time spent in this bootloader.

Comment: Thank you so mouch, I'll test it soon.